# Kubernetes JSON configMap not mounted

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

I am trying to map a configMap in JSON format to my docker image in Kubernetes
I am using config npm package to fetch the configurations.

The idea is that I will have a file development.json in /config directory from there the config package will pick it up. This all works in localhost. The name of the config file is the same as the NODE_ENV variable, which I am also setting in the deployment.yaml

I am using default namespace

This is the beginning of the configMap (I can see it is created in google kubernetes)

I am running ls is the config directory to see if the development.json file has been mounted but it is not. I want the /config to be replaced and only contain the development.json file

I have also tried with the subPath parameter but same result

What am I doing wrong ? Should I see in the events that the configMap is mounted. There is no log of that except when I delete the configMap and try to do the mount, so I figure that the mounting is happening

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: config-development
  namespace: default
data:
  development.json: |
    {
      "production": false,
```

Here is the mount:

```
volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: config-development
      containers:
        - name: salesforce-compare-api
          image: XXXX
          command: ["ls"]
          args: ["config", "-la"]
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          env:
          - name: NODE_ENV
            value: "development"
          volumeMounts:
          - name: config-volume
            mountPath: /config/development.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, when the configmap cannot be mounted, the pod will not even start. So the fact that it started, shows that its mounted.

In any case, your volumeMounts looks problematic.

```
volumeMounts:
  - name: config-volume
    mountPath: /config/development.json
```

This lead to the full configmap being mounted into a folder named development.json, while you actually only want to mount the one file.

Use a [subpath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath) for this.

```
volumeMounts:
  - name: config-volume
    mountPath: /config/development.json
    subPath: development.json
```

That said, if you config folder inside the container is otherwise empty, you can also drop the subpath and mount the configmap to the /config dir, since it will not override anything important.

```
volumeMounts:
  - name: config-volume
    mountPath: /config
```

Comment: I tried that, same thing. The development.json file is not listed in the /config directory. The /config directory is not empty but I read that if you do it without the subPath the whole /config directory in the docker container will be replaced with the mounted data. This is what I want to achieve.

Comment: If you want to achieve this, use the second option presented Apart from this, can you exec into the pod and do a ls on /config to show its contents? You can add this to your question maybe. Also show the full command you are running to get the ls output.

Comment: @jani_r, are you sure you are not confusing absolute and relative path? this one is relative `args: ["config", "-la"]` . It should be `args: ["/config", "-la"]`  if your workdir is not the root of the container.